# Fetching URL from a redirected target using Python

Tags: python, authentication, automation, spotipy

I'm building a Twitch chat-bot, integrating some Spotify features using Spotipy library.

The goal behind the implementation is to achieve full-automated Spotipfy API Authentication for the bot.

How the **Spotify API** and **Spotipy library** work is, an authorization token is needed first in order to do anything over Spotify-end. So that's why, whenever the bot is initially run over my VPS, it prompts me to copy a URL from the console, locate it on a browser to wait for its redirect and paste on the console the redirected URL including the desired token. That's how the authentication object retrieves the token data.

To automate this process, I've seen several solutions via Flask or Django.

Django implementation would be useful for me, since I also have Django environment active on the same VPS, except that Django environment runs on `Python 2.7` while my Twitch chat-bot runs on a separate `Python 3.6` environment. Hence, I would like to keep them separate unless there is no way to implement such automation without listening redirects over Django, Flask or any other web-framework. Unfortunately, my bot can only run on `Python 3.6` or higher.

I'm specifically curious if there is any built-in function or a lightweight library to handle such operation.

The function which I'm using to fetch Spotify Auth token is:

```
def fetchSpotiToken():
global spotiToken, spoti
spotiToken = spotifyAuth.get_cached_token()
if not spotiToken:
    spAuthURL = spotifyAuth.get_authorize_url()
    print(spAuthURL)
    # Prints the URL that Spotify API will redirect to
    authResp = input("Enter URL")
    # Console user is expected to visit the URL and submit the new redirected URL on console
    respCode = spotifyAuth.parse_response_code(authResp)
    spotiToken = spotifyAuth.get_access_token(respCode)
elif spotifyAuth.is_token_expired(spotifyAuth.get_cached_token()):
    spotiToken = spotifyAuth.refresh_access_token(spotiToken["refresh_token"])
spoti = spotipy.Spotify(auth=spotiToken["access_token"])
return [spotiToken, spoti]
```

***PS:*** I've been developing Python only for couple of weeks, even after doing some research, I wasn't able to find a solution to this problem in a way that I need. I'm not sure if it's even possible to achieve it that way. So, if that's impossible, please excuse me for my lack of knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution myself.

It seems that `requests` is a good match for this example.

Following snippet works perfectly for now.

```
def tryFetchSpotiToken():
    global spotiToken, spoti
    try:
        spotiToken = spotifyAuth.get_cached_token()
    except:
        if not spotiToken:
            spAuthURL = spotifyAuth.get_authorize_url()
            htReq = requests.get(spAuthURL)
            htRed = htReq.url
            respCode = spotifyAuth.parse_response_code(htRed)
            spotiToken = spotifyAuth.get_access_token(respCode)
        elif spotifyAuth.is_token_expired(spotifyAuth.get_cached_token()):
            spotiToken = spotifyAuth.refresh_access_token(spotiToken["refresh_token"])
    spoti = spotipy.Spotify(auth=spotiToken["access_token"])
```