# automatic Spotipy Redirect and getting token

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, spotipy

I made an app that works, however, I want to compile it into an executable. I have managed this but rather than let me copy and paste the link into the cmd that opens up it just quits and throws an error.

I have tried to find solutions to this. I have not found a single one that actually works. The closest I have found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63108432/fetching-url-from-a-redirected-target-using-python) howerver this code no longer works.

I have also tried to open another command prompt to output in but I didn't get very far with that as I couldn't figure out how to simply print.

Does anyone have any ideas how I might get around this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix my issue.

I added `--noconfirm` to allow for spotipy to ask for the url. `--add-data` followed by the path for the `kivy_venv` folder.

I found my solution [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6335) by adding the following to the top of my code:

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_NO_ARGS"] = "1"
os.environ['KIVY_IMAGE'] = "pil,sdl2"
os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.expandvars('%AppData%\\Python\\share\\glew\\bin')
os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + os.path.expandvars('%AppData%\\Python\\share\\sdl2\\bin')
```